# Why does the nitrile carbon experience more shielding than a carbonyl carbon in CNMR?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

In organic chemistry lecture, we were given a chart of approximate signal shift ranges for different carbon types in CNMR spectra. carbonyl carbons (C=O) have a range of about 155-210 ppm, but the nitrile group (C≡N) has a signal range of about 110-140 ppm. I understand that oxygen is a more electronegative atom, so it might pull electron density away from the bonded carbon (deshielding), but the C≡N is a more polar bond, which means the electron density spends a lot of time around nitrogen in this bond. Doesn't this imply the C≡N carbon would produce a signal more downfield than that of the C=O carbon?

From the given data ranges, it seems the opposite is true and the carbon of nitrile is more shielded despite the bond polarity.

Answer (score 3):

> **TL;DR:** It's complicated and likely has to do with *paramagnetic shielding* effects rather than the usual arguments based on electron density, ring currents, and so on.
>
> Firstly, because of low-lying π* orbitals, π-bonded carbons typically have lower excitation energies than purely σ-bonded carbons and are thus more deshielded. However, due to the presence of a π-bond order term, alkynes experience less deshielding due to paramagnetic effects. So the general order of chemical shifts is: alkenes > alkynes > alkanes.
>
> Carbonyls are more deshielded than alkenes, and nitriles more deshielded than alkynes (both due to the paramagnetic contribution), but this doesn't overturn the existing bias of alkenes > alkynes.

---

It is instructive to start by comparing alkenes (~120 ppm) vs alkynes (~70 ppm). There is already a large difference between those two. Carbonyls are essentially deshielded alkenes, and nitriles essentially deshielded alkynes. And so it is no longer too surprising that carbonyls come in at a higher chemical shift than nitriles.

The only question left is to ask why sp<sup>2</sup> carbons are generally more deshielded than sp carbons. Although it's tempting to just look purely at the hybridisation and s-percentage, this doesn't explain why the pattern is generally sp<sup>2</sup> > sp > sp<sup>3</sup>. I should first point out that the physical factors controlling <sup>13</sup>C shifts are (usually) markedly different from those controlling <sup>1</sup>H shifts, so any text that tries to "carry over" those ideas is likely incomplete or incorrect. The reason for that is described in further detail [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/62565/16683), and you can see [Hans Reich's excellent website](https://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/nmr/06-cmr-02-shifts.htm) for more information about the various terms that contribute to the chemical shift.

With that out of the way, I will briefly quote from Gunther's *NMR Spectroscopy*, 3rd ed. (p 410):

> For the paramagnetic contribution, early theoretical considerations [...] led to the expression:
>
> $$\sigma_\mathrm{p}^i \approx -\frac{1}{\Delta E} \left(\frac{1}{r_i^3}\right)_\mathrm{2p_z} \left(\color{red}{Q_{ii}} + \sum_{j \neq i} Q_{ij}\right)$$
>
> where $\Delta E$ is a mean electronic excitation energy [...]

I have coloured $Q_{ii}$ in red because it is not in Gunther's text (I suspect this is an error). I have added it to bring it in line with an article by Pople ([*Mol. Phys.* **1964,** *7* (4), 301–306](https://doi.org/10.1080/00268976300101061)).

Note first that the paramagnetic shielding is negative, so a larger magnitude corresponds to a less shielded nucleus, or a higher chemical shift. Now, the "excitation energy" for an alkane is probably a $\sigma \to \sigma^*$ excitation, which is quite large. On the other hand, for unsaturated compounds (alkenes / alkynes), there are low-lying $\pi^*$ orbitals, so $\Delta E$ becomes smaller and $\sigma_\mathrm p$ more negative.* This accounts for why unsaturated groups have higher chemical shifts than alkanes.

It also explains why carbonyls/nitriles are more deshielded than alkenes/alkynes respectively: because a heteroatom (O/N) has a high-energy lone pair, the primary excitation becomes a $n \to \pi^*$ transition which has a smaller $\Delta E$.

> [...] $Q_{ij}$ is a bond order term that originates from the presence of $\pi$-bonds. [...] The bond order term superimposes additional changes that are most pronounced for [...] the $\ce{^{13}C}$ resonances of alkynes. For [alkynes], theory yields $\sum_{j\neq i} Q_{ij} = 0$ as in alkanes, whereas for [the central carbon of] allene $\sum_{j\neq i} Q_{ij} = 0.8$.

Gunther doesn't say exactly what this term would be for a plain old alkene (not allene), but Pople writes that it is 0.44. According to Pople, the $Q_{ii}$ term (in red) is equal to 2, so the overall term in parentheses is equal to 2 for alkynes and 2.44 for alkenes. This means that an alkyne carbon experiences a smaller (less negative) $\sigma_\mathrm p$, and consequently is less deshielded than an alkene carbon.

---

* Note also that $\pi \to \pi^*$ excitations are symmetry-forbidden in the context of paramagnetic shielding, so the primary excitation is probably a $\sigma \to \pi^*$ or $\pi \to \sigma^*$.

Answer (score 0):

The nitrile is sp hybridized while the carbonyl is sp2 hybridized, meaning that the orbitals around the nitrile carbon have more s character, leading to more shielding.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not as simple as that... if this argument was all it took, then sp3 compounds like alkanes should be even more deshielded than sp2 compounds like alkenes/carbonyls. Shifts in unsaturated groups generally have more to do with other effects that aren't related to electron density. This is especially true for 13C shifts. see e.g. https://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/nmr/06-cmr-02-shifts.htm

Comment: The reason for sp2 compounds being more deshielded is due to the planar node. It is an exception to the rule.